# Qt thread pool cannot receive messages using http library

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

The address of the library to use :https://github.com/flaviotordini/http

Thread pool library code

```
SpiderTask::SpiderTask(int id, QString url,QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent},QRunnable()
{
    this->url = url;
    this->id = id;
    setAutoDelete(true);
}

void SpiderTask::run(){
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    int rand = QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(0,10);
    QThread::sleep(rand);
    auto reply = Http::instance().get("https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=" + this->url);
    connect(reply, &HttpReply::finished, this, [=](auto &reply) {
        if (reply.isSuccessful()) {
            emit recvState(this->id, reply.body());
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Something's wrong here" << reply.statusCode() << reply.reasonPhrase();
        }
        qDebug() << reply.body();
    });
}
```

main execution code

```
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(ui->threadVloumelineEdit->text().toInt());

        ui->spiderTableView->model()->rowCount();

        int rows = ui->spiderTableView->model()->rowCount();
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            QString url = ui->spiderTableView->model()->index(r,0).data().toString();
            QString status = ui->spiderTableView->model()->index(r,1).data().toString();
            SpiderTask *t = new SpiderTask(r,url);
                connect(t,&SpiderTask::recvState,this,&MainWindow::changeSpiderState);
            QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(t);
        }
```

After the code enters the run function, connect is not executed and the signal is not received. How to solve it?

Expect to receive http request results

Comment: Why do believe `connect` is not called?  What are the calls to `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` and `QThread::sleep(rand)` supposed to achieve?  Sorry, but the code shown really makes no sense to me.  From what I've read the call to `Http::get` is non-blocking so there's no need to call it on a separate thread anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Http library is not designed to be used from multiple threads, first time you call `Http::instance()` it creates instance in current thread (some thread in thread pool), accessing `Http::instance()` is not protected by mutex, so accessing it from multiple threads can cause undefined behaviour.

`QRunnable::setAutoDelete(true)` instructs `QThreadPool` to delete task after `SpiderTask::run` exited, but `SpiderTask::run` exits before `HttpReply::finished` handler is called, `emit recvState` will never be invoked because SpiderTask is deleted by then (you cannot emit signals from deleted object). You can add `qDebug()` to `SpiderTask`'s destructor to verify that.

If you want tasks to be deleted by `QThreadPool` you need to block `run` function until reply is received and handled. You can use while loop with `QThread::msleep` and `qApp->processEvents()` or local `QEventLoop` for that. But you don't and cant, since you use `SpiderTask` objects after `QThreadPool` is done running them.

`QNetworkAccessManager` and `Http` have asyncronous event-loop friendly API, which means all heavy lifting is already offloaded from calling thread to worker thread, which means you dont need any more threads to use it. Which means you can simply use in main thread.

```cpp
int rows = ui->spiderTableView->model()->rowCount();
for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    QString url = ui->spiderTableView->model()->index(r,0).data().toString();
    QString status = ui->spiderTableView->model()->index(r,1).data().toString();
    auto reply = Http::instance().get("https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=" + url);
    connect(reply, &HttpReply::finished, this, [=](auto &reply) {
        if (reply.isSuccessful()) {
            // use reply here
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Something's wrong here" << reply.statusCode() << reply.reasonPhrase();
        }
    });
}
```

Using QThreadPool for that have no benefits at all, it will not increase speed or gui responsiveness (likely, it will decrease it, due to overhead), and will only complicade your code and will require extra debug efforts.

For tidiness, you can move this code into model's code.